# How to SSH a curl command

Tags: linux, shell, curl, ssh

env = GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Situation:
SystemA=No internet. SystemB=Yes internet.
SystemA has a log file. SystemA wants SystemB to send a curl command for him.

SystemA$
`ssh SystemB curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "$data" $hook`
= fail

SystemB$
`curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "$data" $hook` = success

How do I achieve this without SystemA 'scp'ing the log file to SystemB?
It's heavily schedule related so I want SystemA let SystemB work.

---

EDIT:
I narrowed down the problem :

On SystemB:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{$data}' $hookurl` = success
`curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d {$data} $hookurl` = fail

So when I type in SystemA
`ssh SystemB curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{$data}" $hookurl`
It actually runs with `-d {$data}` on SystemB. How can I fix this?

---

Update:
`ssh SystemB curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "'{$data}'"  $hookurl`

did work and actually sent data to url,
but `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Unknown error` occurred again.

Comment: In my case, the errors were  
```curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: channel; Unknown error
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: #test,; Unknown error
bash: line 2: text:: command not found
bash: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `}'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command :

```
ssh SystemB /bin/bash <<< "$(declare -p data hook);"'curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "$data" "$hook"'
```

`"$(declare -p data hook);"` takes variable definitions from SystemA and passes them to SystemB

Answer (score 0):

Use sshfs perhaps

on systemB

sshfs -p'ssh port' -o password_stdin user@systemA:/home/user/dir /home/user/dir <<< 'passwd'

Comment: I really want SystemA to control everything. Since I have to deal with so much more systems. Otherwise I have to configure every other systems.

Comment: Can you add further explanation to your post. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to know more.